# How do I apply the `loading="lazy"` attribute to responsive media?

Tags: media, 9, performance

On my Drupal 9 installation when I create an "image" field, Drupal automatically adds the `loading="lazy"` attribute.

When I create a "media" field with an "Adaptive Image Styles" display, the `loading="lazy"` attribute is not applied.

How to apply the `loading="lazy"` attribute to responsive media?

If I go to a media image, there is "lazy" :

[image]

If I go to a media image with the adaptive image style, there is no "lazy" :

[image]

**UPDATED WITH cilefen REPLY**

I tested on Drupal 9.4 and it seems that the update does not fix the problem. `loading="lazy"` is unavailable for "Responsive image" :

[image]

While it is available for non-responsive image :

[image]

So I rest my question, how to apply `loading="lazy"` on the "Responsive image" ? This is a big problem for page performance.

Comment: If you are using the Blazy contrib module, this sounds like a feature request for that module: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/blazy

Comment: @PatrickKenny I don't use a contrib module, it's drupal 9 which adds blazy on all images except for adaptive image styles

Comment: @zoulou66 That is not true. Core adds loading=lazy attribute: https://www.drupal.org/node/3173719

Comment: @cilefen This is what I want on my images, but it does not add it on the media with the adaptive image style

Comment: I updated my question, with screenshots to better explain

Comment: I amended my answer with the most current information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an active area a research and development in Drupal Core. Although there is no quick fix, [this issue is the locus of work](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3192234). Test the patches and provide feedback.